# Passing Hard Arguments

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to hardcode arguments that are passed to the [OpenCV Command Line Parser](http://%20https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/command_line_parser.html). In the [object_detection file](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/object_detection.cpp), I have added the code as such, so that I do not have to enter the file name via command-line:

**Line 40-48:**

```
void drawPred(int classId, float conf, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, Mat& frame);

void callback(int pos, void* userdata);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // This line added below:
    argv[1]="-input /home/Videos/test.mp4";

    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keys);
    parser.about("Use this script to run object detection deep learning networks using OpenCV.");
    if (argc == 1 || parser.has("help"))
```

OpenCV skips using this file, and switches to camera instead. How can I hardcode the arguments, before they are passed to the Command Line Parser ?

Comment: in addition to the answer from swift; you'll find that your program name should be argument 0; `-input` should be the argument 1;  `/home/Videos...` should be the 2nd

Answer (score 2):

and what is `argc`? if it's 0, it'll be ignored, and pointer in argv will be NULL, so you get UB. Also, modifying system storage supplied to main is a bad idea, it's likely an UB because you don't have proper storage available to store string.

The only proper way about this is create intermediate variables. Note that array should be NULL-terminated.

Comment: Incorrect in many ways. `argv` is a pointer to an array of `char*`, unconditionally of `argc`. In particular, that array is an `char*[argc+1]`, with the last `char*` being a null pointer. The array *is* writeable (i.e. the pointers). He's not writing a string; instead he sets `argv[1]` to an existing string literal.  (no `strcpy`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `argc,argv` are an old-style C mechanism. You can't simply insert a value in the C array `char**`. Instead, you must create a new array with one extra element. (Your existing code *overwrites* `argv[1]`)

Now there's more unusual stuff. `argv` is an array with `argc+1` elements, the last one of which is `nullptr`. Since you're inserting a new element, you must create an `char*[argc+2]*`, copy all `argc` elements, append the pointer to your string, and then terminate the new array with `nullptr`.

You can now pass the new array and `argc+1` to `CommandLineParser`.

Answer (score -1):

The goal of argc and is to pass argument t"-input /home/Videos/test.mp4");
    argv[2] = NULL;hrough the main, if you are using a GNU / UNIX distribution, just pass argument like it:

```
argc = 2
argv[1] = strdup("-input /home/Videos/test.mp4");
argv[2] = NULL;

CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keys);
parser.about("Use this script to run object detection deep learning networks using OpenCV.");
if (argc == 1 || parser.has("help"))
```

or just use "normal" way and pass argument through our binary, like

> ./a.out "-input /home/Videos/test.mp4"